# Entity Framework 5 .Include() is not loading records if there are related entities that have been deleted

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, model-binding

I have a database with a 1..many relationship between two tables, call them Color and Car. A Color is associated 1..many with Cars. In my case, it's critical that Colors can be deleted any time. No cascade delete, so if a Color is deleted, the Car's Color_ID field points to something that doesn't exist. This is OK. They are related via a FK named Color_ID.

The problem comes in when I do this:

```
var query = context.Cars.Include(x => x.Colors);
```

This only returns Cars that have an associated Color record that exists. What I really want is ALL the Cars, even if their color doesn't exist, so I can do model binding with a GridView, i.e.
`<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Colors == null ? "Color Deleted!" : Item.Colors %>' />`

All of this works fine if I remove the .Include() and resort to lazy loading. Then Item.Car.Color is null. Perfect. However I'm seriously concerned about doing way too many database queries for a massive result set, which is certainly possible.

One solution to avoid excessive db queries is to return an anonymous type from the datasource query with all the specific related bits of info that I need for the grid and convert all my "Item" style bindings to good 'ol Eval(). But then I lose the strong typing, and the simplicity that Value Provider attributes bring. I'd hate to re-write all that.

Am I right, do I have to choose one or the other? How can I shape my query to return all the Car records, even if there is no Color record? I think I'm screwed if I try to eager load with .Include(). I need like a .IncludeWithNulls() or something.

UPDATE: Just thought of this. I don't know how ugly this is as far as query cost, but it works. Is there a better way??

```
var query = context.Cars.Include(x => x.Colors);
var query2 = context.Cars.Where(x => !context.Colors.Any(y => y.Color_ID == x.Color_ID);
return query.Union(query2);
```

Comment: This `Include` gets translated into an `INNER JOIN` (for a required relationship), so EF expects that the relationship is enforced in the database (but it isn't apparently in your case).

Comment: Aha, after looking at the generated SQL before and after setting the multiplicity for the "1" side to "0", I can see that changing the multiplicity to 0 solves the problem. It then generates a left outer join - problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect end multiplicity. What I really needed was not 1..many but 0..many. That way, Entity Framework generates a left outer join instead of an inner join from the .Include(). Which makes sense, there may be zero actual Color records in the example above. The thing that confused me was that in the SQL database, I never set those foreign key fields to nullable because at the time of creation, they always required a valid foreign key. So I set them to nullable and fixed up my .edmx table and everything is working. I did have to add a few more null checks here and there such as the one in my question above, that weren't strictly necessary before, since the .Include is now pulling in records that reference missing related entities, but no big deal.

So I lose out on the non-null checking at the db level, but I gain some consistent logic in my LINQ queries for how those tables actually relate and what I expect to get back.